# What requirement to create CUSTOM SHIPPING METHOD IN MAGENTO?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, stores, ecommerce-tracking

[ Theoretical answer NOT CODE Example ]

Why we required to create custom shipping method in Magento.

**OR**

we can say in which case(s) it is important to make custom shipping method for our eCommerce?

Required theoretical answer ONLY or You can explain by an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why we need to create module there are two reason.

> 1. The functionality does not exist in magento modules
> 2. You want to extend the magento core functionality
> 3. if you think you do  better then magento

if you take the [example](https://amasty.com/shipping-extensions.html) of these extension have different functionality. They all related to shipping.

Comment: Please as mentioned in question that PLEASE EXPLAIN BY AN EXAMPLE ....

Comment: seems this is first time, we both answered for same question :-) I am going to downvote this answer to get `critic` badge.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento kindly add the down-vote reason too..

Comment: as i already said, until now i didt got critic badge, if i downvote, i will get that :-)

Comment: @BabyinMagento you just want to earn the badge?

Comment: yes, you are right & i will feel happy if i downvote your answers....

Comment: @BabyinMagento do it if it make you feel happy...

Comment: wow, wow yours golden heart champ....

Comment: @QaisarSatti YOUR EXAMPLE IS PERFECT TO UNDERSTAND FOR BEGINNER.... THANKS.....

Answer (score 1):

Answer of @QaisarSatti is correct, and to add more if [link](https://amasty.com/shipping-extensions.html) is expired.

Below is the situations to create the CUSTOM SHIPPING METHOD to you MAGENTO STORE....

- Adjust shipping process to your legal and business needs.
- Block shipping carriers or some methods of shipping carriers
- Modify shipping rates according to your business needs
- Shipping rules based on order and product attributes
- Unlimited shipping methods
- Specific rates for a product or a group of products
- Automatically display default shipping methods
- Identify customer's   address with GeoIP
- Manage access to payment and shipping methods by groups
- Customers see only the methods assigned to their group
- Indicate individual flat shipping rate for each product
- Forget about incorrect shipping rates
- Enable visitors to select days and time of delivery
- Exclude any dates from your delivery plan
- Multiple percent-based shipping methods
- Minimal and maximal shipping prices for each method
- Create numerous fees for extra services
- Configure fees based on payment and shipping methods
- Improved order addresses management
- Edit addresses with just
  a couple clicks

Answer (score 0):

if Default magento shipping methods don't support **client** needs, then we need to create custom shipping method.

**example** : If we need to charge different shipping charges for different products.

**Edit**

for Product A, client want to charge 10 $ as shipping charge & for 
for Product B, client want to charge 20 $ as shipping charge & so on....

you can [try this Example](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=shipping+extension&pl=0) & it give more options for you and this is better example than what @Qaisar Satti mentioned in his answer :-)

Comment: "Client Needs"  mean what ? Please Explain by an example ...

Comment: @UpendrasinhJadeja example : If client wants to `charge different shipping charges for different products.`

Comment: @UpendrasinhJadeja check my update in answer.....

Comment: @Babyinmagneto, any two product example, to compare charges...

Comment: @UpendrasinhJadeja sorry, i did't understood, did you checked my update in answer ?

Comment: @Babyinmagneto  So, to add more, its required when Different type of product, Different locations, not sure to Different categories, Different suppliers  and so on based on  shipping condition ... ? At those circumstances/situations we required to create CUSTOM SHIPPING METHODS.....  you can add more if anything left...

Comment: @UpendrasinhJadeja please check my update....

Answer (score 0):

Try this following extension from magento connect manager [Flat Rate Shipping Per Product](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/flat-rate-shipping-per-product-6.html)